# Retrieving file information of specific date using powershell

Tags: powershell

I have a base folder as:

```
D:\St\Retail\AMS\AMS\FTP-FromClient\AMS
```

It contains various folders of dates:

```
2022-04-01
2022-04-02
...
...

2022-02-02
2021-05-05
2019-04-12
```

And each of these folders contains own files inside the folder. So, I want to retrieve all the filename inside the folder if it has `2022-04`. So if the folder has `'2022-04'` as the base name ,I need to retreive all the file inside the folder like `'2022-04-01','2022-04-02','2022-04-03'.` The way I tried is:

```
cls
$folerPath = 'D:\St\Retail\AMS\AMS\FTP-FromClient\AMS'
$files = Get-ChildItem $folerPath
[System.Collections.ArrayList]$data = @()
foreach ($f in $files) {
    $a = Get-ChildItem $f.FullName
    foreach ($inner in $a) {
        echo $inner.FullName
        $outfile = $inner.FullName -match '*2022-04*'
        $datepart = $inner.FullName.split('\')[-1]
        if ($outfile) {
            $data.add($datepart + '\' + $inner.Name.Trim())
        }
    }
}
```

My final `$data` may contains like this:

```
2022-04-01/abc.txt
2022-04-02/cde.pdf
2022-04-03/e.xls
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by first collecting the directories you want to explore and then loop over these to get the files inside.

Using a calculated property you can output in whatever format you like:

```
$folderPath = 'D:\St\Retail\AMS\AMS\FTP-FromClient\AMS'

$data = Get-ChildItem -Path $folderPath -Filter '2022-04*' -Directory | ForEach-Object {
    $dir = $_.Name
    (Get-ChildItem -Path $_.FullName -File | 
     Select-Object @{Name = 'FolderFile'; Expression = {'{0}\{1}' -f $dir, $_.Name}}).FolderFile
}
```

After this, $data would be a string array with this content:

```
2022-04-01\abc.txt
2022-04-02\cde.pdf
2022-04-03\e.xls
```

Comment: Its magical the way you wrote.

Answer (score 0):

By using [wildcards](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_wildcards) for both directory and file name, you only need a single `Get-ChildItem` call:

```sh
$folderPath = 'D:\St\Retail\AMS\AMS\FTP-FromClient\AMS'
$folderDate = '2022-04'

[array] $data = Get-ChildItem "$folderPath/$folderDate*/*" -File | ForEach-Object{ 
    # Join-Path's implicit output will be captured as an array in $data.
    Join-Path $_.Directory.Name $_.Name 
}
```

`$data` will be an array of file paths like this:

```text
2022-04-01\abc.txt
2022-04-02\cde.pdf
2022-04-03\e.xls
```

**Notes:**

- `[array] $data` makes sure that the variable always contains an array. Otherwise PowerShell would output a *single string value* when only a single file is found. This could cause problems, e. g. when you want to iterate over `$data` by index, you would iterate over the characters of the single string instead.
- To make this answer platform-independent I'm using *forward* slashes in the `Get-ChildItem` call which work as path separators under both Windows and *nix platforms.
- [`Join-Path`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/join-path) is used to make sure the output paths use the expected *default path separator* (either `/` or `\`) of the platform.